# Deploy Adobe Pro X GPO Issues

Tags: group-policy, adobe, deployment, adobe-acrobat

I am trying to deploy adobe pro x extended to clients machines. The deploy is working fine except when you launch Adobe, it asks to enter the serial number. I have used the adobe customization x wizard and generated the MSI and MST files and they include the serial number but no matter what it still asks for the serial number.

Anyone know if there is a step I am missing here? I go into GPO, computer, software installs and new package and point it to the msi that the wizard has created but it seems it is not processing the MST file for some reason, its set to install english only and still installs as english french and german.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this myself...was a missed step and didn't put the serial number in the ABCPY.INI file in the same dir as the MSI file.